# jQuery datepicker - code local won't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I load the datepicker scripts from code.jquery.com.I try now to copy them to my own Server, because of performance and security reasons.

Altough I have Changed my css and copy both scripts, it will not work. The working Version is
http://www.ruhrlink.de/heute.php?tag=Heute&ort=Ruhrgebiet&nonight=0
and the Local is
http://www.ruhrlink.de/termine.php?ort=Ruhrgebiet

I am new in JS and can't find the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have these 3 `script` tags in your body:

1. `<script src="jquery1.11.2.js"></script> //loads jQuery`
2. `<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script> //loads jQuery UI`
3. `<script>$("#datepick").datepicker({...})</script> //initializing DatePicker`

The problem is in first `script` tag. It contains the code for `jQuery UI` and not the `jQuery`. See the following two links from the **not working** site to verify.

[jQuery UI.js](http://www.ruhrlink.de/jquery-ui.js)
 
 [jQuery.js](http://www.ruhrlink.de/jquery1.11.2.js)

You need to change the script in **`jquery1.11.2.js`** from `jQuery UI` to [`jQuery`](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js)

**Edit:**

1. Get jQuery from this link: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js
2. Copy all of contents from this file and replace them in your **`jquery1.11.2.js`** file.

Comment: I vave searched the query 1.11.2 Script for Jquery UI and found only one point, where it is no comment: 
$.error( "jQuery UI Tabs: Mismatching fragment identifier." ); 
Changed into jQuery, but it don't help.

Comment: Hurra, it works .Thanks you a lot. It seems only to be the older Version 1.10.2.
Maybe you know something about CSS? The Formatting on this page is smaller that on the Heute Page. The Datepicker is there formated in bigger letters. What can be the cause? And how to transmit it to the know running page? I learn a lot this morning, thanks.

Comment: @RolfBlenn: Please accept the answer and for the other problem you would have to provide some code.

Comment: How to accept it here? I have only one link, Share. 
Code? I dont know where the code is, wich make it happen. Some Format is coming from jquery.ui.css, some of my own yuri.css. The Yuris.css is the same, but on the Heute page the datepicker is presented in a better form.

Comment: there're a lot of things confusing here. like `Yuris.css` and `Heute page`. can you recreate the issue online on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I have to learn JSFiddle, and i think its not possible, to move the whole Configuration to it. Under the HEUTE Button is the old Code, Loaded from jquery.com. Under the Button ALLES is the Script loaded local. You can see the difference visual. The CSS included 1.10.2 seems to be older than in 1.11.2, and let some settings from the CSS above (in this case, my Yuri.ss) not Pass.In the 1.11 the CSS is newer and let pass from the css above.OK, now I can use a local copy and try to use the newer css. Accepting I have found in the meantime.

Comment: I think updating the css to `1.11.2` is the only possible solution without looking at code.

Comment: I agree. But how to change the css in the 11.10.2? I searched in it for jquery-ui.css to locate the postion, but hav'nt found it.

Comment: did you try replacing the new css file with old one, instead of replacing contents of old file?

Comment: That was how to begin this discussion . At have a first loaded the1.11.2, but I used you tip with the 1.10.2, because the 1.11.2 dont worked.
A,d this css is loaded from the Jquery servr, wich a want to avoid.

Comment: right, I thought it was the other way round. this makes things quite difficult to figure out. for now, you can try using `inspect` to check which `css` is actually being applied.

Comment: I have inspected with firefox, I found the name of the css Its yquery-ui.css, but I dont find it  in the 1.10.2 Code to replace it with the never css of 1.11.2. 
The Problem is, the Complete 1.11.2 dont work, and in 1.10.2., wich works, is an older css. Somewhere.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to search for the exact styles and then replace them. or write your own css that should override the `jQuery` styling.

Comment: Mhh. I can search overwrite in my owm css. But this dont stops do download the CSS from JQUERY.
And this was the target for the wole action, avoid download from other Resouces. A false DNS Entry can put a complete other js File as download, and this query needs Time, too.
I must look, where the css ist situated in the script.

Comment: I have know learned more. Copy the css file and the images, and now it works on all pages. On ALLES and the days (Heute, Morgen ... ).

Comment: @RolfBlenn: that's great. happy coding :)